# (TF) Saving model with its history.history to use it in the following training sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to save TF model with the whole information around training such as history and at what epoch the training ended? I need this information for the sake of the continuity of the training during the following sessions and saving relevant data.

I tried several methods of saving models (model.save, tf.saved_model, tf.train.Checkpoint) but none of them has the above information after loading (tf.keras.model.load_model, tf.train.Checkpoint.restore with assert_consumed and expect_partial where needed).

Is my only option saving the data in separate files and setting it manually after loading the model, i.e. model.history.history = (dict)history, model._current_epoch = (int)epoch_the_last_training_ended?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to save on the "manual" save of the relevant data.

1. First, I save model.history.history whenever I save the checkpoint and on_train_end with

```
joblib.dump(model.history.history, path)
```

2. When I start the program, I check if the checkpoint exists, if yes, I load it and, at the same time, I check if the history exists and if it does I load it and store in model._history variable since model.history.history is only created after you start training!

```
model._history = joblib.load(path)
```

Additionally, I set model._current_epoch value to keep track of the last epoch:

```
model._current_epoch = len(model.history.history[list(model.history.history.keys())[0]])
```

3. After starting training I assign the proper value of model.history.history and remove the old value.

```
def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
   if '_history' in self.model.__dict__:
      self.model.history.history = self.model._history
      del self.model._history
```

Not the most elegant solution but it serves the purpose for now.